# text-shadow not applying in Opera

Tags: html, opera, shadow, css

I've added a text block to an area of my page that uses parallax scrolling. This text block has the necessary style-rule to apply a small text shadow.
Problem is, in Opera, I have to set it as `!important`, or it won't do it. Instead, it sets it to:

```
* {
    text-shadow: transparent 0px 0px 0px,
                 rgba(0,0,0, 0.68) 0px 0px 0px !important
}
```

Weird thing is that none of my code has any instruction that tells it to do that.

It works in Firefox.

**Declaration**

```
h1.mainText {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 46px;
    line-height: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px fade(black, 40%);
    margin-top: 186px;
    [...]
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: well you have important on the * rule so you need important to override it. You should find out where that * rule is coming from. It must come from something since it cannot create itself. It is a very slow selector

Comment: I don't have the `*` rule, it's being put there. But I just found out why - it's the Opera Font Rendering Extension. Have just turned it off, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the Opera Font Rendering Extension. Have just turned it off, and it works like a charm.